# How to solve multiple coupled differential equations by MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

The differential equations are as follows

> \begin{align}
> \dot x_i &= \gamma(\mu-r^2_i)x_i -\omega_iy_i +\varepsilon F(t) +\tau\sin(R_i-\phi_i)  \tag{13}  \\
> \dot y_i &= \gamma(\mu-r^2_i)y_i +\omega_ix_i  \tag{14}  \\
> \dot \omega_i &= -\varepsilon F(t)\frac{y_i}{r_i}  \tag{15}  \\ 
> \dot \alpha_i &= \eta x_i F(t)  \tag{16}  \\ 
> \dot \phi_0 &= 0  \tag{17}  \\ 
> \dot \phi_i &= \sin\left(R_i-\operatorname{sgn}(x_i)\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{y_i}{r_i}\right)-\phi_i\right), \quad\forall\ i\neq 0  \tag{18}  \\ 
> \end{align}
>   with
>   $$R_i = \frac{\omega_i}{\omega_0} \operatorname{sgn}(x_0) \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{y_0}{\sqrt{x^2_0+y^2_0}}\right)  \tag{19}$$
>   and
>   $$F(t) = P_{\text{teach}}(t) -\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i x_i  \tag{20}$$
>   $$P_{\text{teach}}=0.8 \sin(15t) +\cos(30t)-1.4 \sin(45t)-0.5 \cos(60t)  \tag{21}$$
>   And the initial conditions are as follows
>   $$\alpha_i(0) = \phi_i(0) = 0,  x_i(0) = 1,  y_i(0) = 0\ \forall\ i, \mu=1, \gamma=8, \varepsilon=0.9, \eta=0.5, \tau=2.$$
>   The frequencies $\omega_i(0)$ are uniformly distributed from $6$ to $70$.

---

Based on the image description, we have $5$ variables, $x$, $y$, $\omega$, $\alpha$ and $\phi$.

So how to solve the ODEs if we have $4$ equation sets ($i = 1, 2, 3, 4$)?
And the $x$, $y$, $\omega$, $\alpha$ and $\phi$ will be vectors respectively.

I just thought that the `ode45` command can solve it. In that case, we must split the ODEs to $4 \times 5=20$ equations?

However, if we get many equation sets (for example $i= 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 100$), how should we solve this problem?

Differential equations are derived from this paper:

Righetti L, Buchli J, Ijspeert A J.: *From Dynamic Hebbian Learning for Oscillators to Adaptive Central Pattern Generators[C]* || Proceedings of $3$rd International Symposium on *Adaptive Motion in Animals and Machines* -- AMAM $2005$. Verlag ISLE, Ilmenau, $2005$.

Comment: "guys," not "gays"

Comment: @MichaelLee Sorry for that, it has been modified

Comment: It's possible that my question has gone wrong, and after all, I've got the support of -3. So, when you don't support this question, you can tell me how to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the vector and elementwise array operations that Matlab provides. That is, you take the input vector and cut it into the parts for $x,y,...$ and then do the operations on them never even declaring an index. Something like

```
dotu = odefunc(t,u)
    x = u(1:N)
    y = u(N+1,2*N)
    ....

    r2 = x.^2+y.^2
    r = r2.^0.5
    ....
    doty = gamma*(mu-r2).*y+omega.*x
    Ft=F(t)
    dotomega = -epsilon*Ft*y./r
    ...
```

and in the end join the derivatives back together in the order of the state vector.

Comment: Thank you and your time. According to your method, the problem has been solved. Thanks again。

Comment: It's a pity that I can't vote you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit my question, and now I know I should edit my formula through latex instead of sticking to the picture, and correctly write the mathematical form of $x, y$.
In addition, I know that you read the paper carefully, and then add the initial condition for the differential equations.  "The frequencies  $\omega_i(0)$ are uniformly distributed from 6 to 70."
Thank you again, Lutz

Comment: It was a mix of copy-paste and editing. The minus signs break the copy, and there was a line break after each letter, so it was not entirely trivial, but I would not have typed all the greek symbols by hand.

Comment: Yeah, I see. you've really been a big help. Thanks.